# read a file for a particular input format

Tags: c

How to read a file in c when the given input format is

```
4
5
3
a,b
b,c
c,a
```

Please help...this my file scanning function. here m should store 4 ,n should store 5 and l should store 3. then col1 will store{abc} and col2will store{bca}
m n , l are int.
col1 and col2 are char arrays
The third line of the file indicates a value 3 , which refers that there are three line below it and it contain 3 pairs of characters.

```
i = 0, j = 0;
while (!feof(file))
{
  if(j==0)
  {
    fscanf(file,"%s\t",&m);
    j++;
  }
  else if(j==1)
  {
    fscanf(file,"%s\t",&n);
    j++;
  }
  else if(j==2)
  {
    fscanf(file,"%s\t",&l);
    j++;
  }
  else
  {
    /* loop through and store the numbers into the array */
    fscanf(file, "%s%s", &col1[i],&col2[i]);
    i++;
  }
}
```

but my result is not coming please tell how to proceed ....

Comment: Is the file always 6 lines long?

Comment: no the third line have a value 3 , which indicates that there are three line below it and it contain pairs of characters.

Comment: You're going about this the wrong way. Remove the `while` loop. Then write the code to process the first row. Only use the while loop for rows that are being processed in the same way (those using `col1`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED** to allow reading of variable number of lines

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  int value1, value2, value3, i;
  char *col1, *col2;
  char lineBuf[100];
  FILE* file;

  file = fopen("scanme.txt","r");

  fgets(lineBuf, 100, file);
  sscanf(lineBuf, "%d", &value1);
  fgets(lineBuf, 100, file);
  sscanf(lineBuf, "%d", &value2);
  fgets(lineBuf, 100, file);
  sscanf(lineBuf, "%d", &value3);

  // create space for the character columns - add one for terminating '\0'
  col1 = calloc(value3 + 1, 1);
  col2 = calloc(value3 + 1, 1);

  for(i = 0; i < value3; i++) {
    fgets(lineBuf, 100, file);
    sscanf(lineBuf, "%c,%c", &col1[i], &col2[i]);
  }
  fclose(file);

  printf("first three values: %d, %d, %d\n", value1, value2, value3);
  printf("columns:\n");
  for (i = 0; i < value3; i++) {
    printf("%c  %c\n", col1[i], col2[i]);
  }

  // another way of printing the columns:
    printf("col1: %s\ncol2: %s\n", col1, col2);
}
```

I performed none of the usual error checking etc - this is just to demonstrate how to read things in. This produced the expected output with the test file you had. I hope you can take it from here.

Comment: here instead of the 3 in the for loop . if i use value3 . Your code is not working properly. My point is the third line will tell me how many character pairs will be there after it here 3rd line is 3 , no of character pairs will be 3 only.

Comment: Please explain what you are saying. This works exactly for the file you gave (3 numbers followed by 3 lines); if you expect the number of lines to be variable you need to explain this in your question.

Comment: I understand now. I will modify the code accordingly. Give me one minute.

Comment: I am sorry to see that you did not like my solution. Is it still not working for you?

Answer (score 2):

A few pointers:

1. Don't use `feof()`, it's never needed for code like this.
2. Read a full line at once, with `fgets()`.
3. Then parse the line, using e.g. `sscanf()`.
4. *Check the return values* from I/O functions, they can fail (for instance at end of file).